# How to count unique votes in Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app where users can vote posts and create their own posts. Since a document can store maximum 1 Mb, I don't know to track unique votes and vote counts.

When I create a new user, I create it like this:

```
collection('users').document(user.uid).setData({
        'name': name + ' ' + surname,
        'email': user.email,
        'registerDate' : DateTime.now(),
        'isEmailVerified': user.isEmailVerified,// TODO: Email Verification
        'location': location,
        'photoUrl': user.photoUrl,
        'posts' : [],

      });
```

When I create a new post, I create it like this:

```
collection('posts').document(imageId).setData({
        'userId': user.uid,
        'user' : user.displayName,
        'title' : title,
        'post' : post,
        'location': location,
        'postDate' : DateTime.now(),
        'upVote' : 1,
        'downVote' : 0,
        'absVote' : 0,
        'votedBy' : [user.uid], // list of users who voted the post.

      });
```

I also add the post to the user's post array.

I think I am making a mistake by 'votedBy' field in the 'posts' collection. This field may fill the document's maximum size which is 1 Mb. Is there a better approach to keep track of votes?

I think I also can't store votes in users collection. In case a user votes too many posts the limited size will be exceeded again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to implement unbounded lists is using one document per item in a  new sub-collection: `users` under `posts` .

In your case:

```
posts/:postId/users/:userId
```

Firestore is designed to massively scale up the number of documents in a collection, you won’t have any scaling issues.

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand what you meant exactly by ``` posts/:postId/users/:userId ``` Do you suggest me to create a subcollection under each post document? The subcollection will be created in a document so It will exceed 1 Mb again, am I wrong?

Comment: I found this: "Subcollection doesn't affect the parent document's size in any way. " Thanks!

Comment: Great ! have fun :)